# What exactly Mending ability does?

Tags: might-and-magic-duel-of-champions

What's the effect of Mending ability in Might & Magic Duel of Champions? I found a card in a booster that gives this ability to creatures but it does not explain the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the entry on this card](http://www.mmdocdb.com/card/chosen_of_elrath-382), Mending heals all damage to the creature at the end of your turn, if it does not attack.

> **Mending** (If this creature doesn't attack during your turn, heal all damage from it at the end of your turn.)